# How to read messages destructively from RabbitMq queue using SimpleMessageListenerContainer bean

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need a help to implement a SimpleMessageListenerContainer in a manner that it removes the message, un-transactionally, as soon as read by the message receiver.

In my case, irrespective of successful or unsuccessful transactions, the message put to the queue hangs somewhere (not in queue), and is processed repeatedly on every operation that reads from the queue. So all other messages put to the queue remain unaccessible, and only the first one is re-processed every time.

The other strange thing is that, I can not see the messages landing/queuing on the queue, i.e. the queue depth never changes on the Rabbit management console, but just the message rate taking a jump on every write to the queue.

Below is the code snippet of my Java configuration. It will be of great help if someone can point out the mistake in here:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.xxx.muppets"})
public class MuppetMessageConsumerConfig {

private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
@Value("${rabbit.queue.name}")
private String queueName;

@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange");
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
}

@Bean
MuppetMsgReceiver muppetMsgReceiver(){
    return new MuppetMsgReceiver();
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(MuppetMsgReceiver muppetMsgReceiver){
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(muppetMsgReceiver, "receiveMessage");
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(NONE);
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
}
```

My message receiver class is as below:

```
public class MuppetMsgReceiver {

private String muppetMessage;

private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

public MuppetMsgReceiver() {
    this.countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
}

public MuppetMsgReceiver(CountDownLatch latch) {
    this.countDownLatch = latch;        
    CountDownLatch getCountDownLatch() {
    return countDownLatch;
}

public void receiveMessage(String receivedMessage) {
    countDownLatch.countDown();
    this.muppetMessage = receivedMessage;
}

public String getMuppetMessage() {
    return muppetMessage;
}
}
```

This complete code is based upon the [getting started example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/) of Spring but is not helping due to non-destructive reads from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcknowledgeMode=NONE` means the broker acks the message as soon as it's **sent** to the consumer, not when the consumer receives it so your observed behavior makes no sense to me. It is quite unusual to use this ack mode but the message will be gone as soon as it's sent. This is likely a problem with your code. TRACE logging will help you see what's going on.

Comment: I completely agree to it Gary, and that's the whole reason of setting Ack Mode as None. I think it might be useful for me to understand how SimpleMessageListenerContainer works. I had expected it to read messages from the queue only when demanded but looks like the created bean of the receiver consumes the message as soon as its published on the Broker. Would you please be able to assist me if this understanding is correct, and if so, where are all the read messages kept/stored? That storage is the place which looks un-flushed to me.

Comment: They are not "stored"; they are written to a queue in the `BlockingQueueConsumer` (which is sized based on the `prefetchCount` to avoid an OOM condition when the consumer can't keep up). The consumer thread removes each message and invokes the listener bean; there is no possibility of redelivery of a message with this scenario.

Comment: The `BlockingQueueConsumer` is something managed by RabbitMq, and in such case it's still unsure why my application would be mis-behaving and managing to fetch only the first message every time. I will still give it a look and workout with my test cases. In case you are aware of any possible reasons for this (mis)behaviour, please do let me know.

Comment: No. It's internal to the SMLC. As I said, turn on TRACE debugging.

Comment: I have happened to dig down to the issue. It was really the way I've mis-understood and implemented message receiver. I had wished to receive messages from queue only when demanded BUT the implementation of the listener container did not meet the need and hence the issue. That  is now fixed with a workaround. However am hitting another confusion at the moment i.e. the messages are read in LIFO order than the expected FIFO from the queue. Is that configurable any how, such that I receive messages in FIFO only?

Comment: That's not the case, it's FIFO only. Use RabbitTemplate.receive() instead of a container to get messages on demand.

Comment: Thanks for the help you provided Gary. It's all sorted with Sync message reading now.